# Selective import of CSVs based on filename

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm analyzing the Daily Fishing Effort data from Global Fishing Watch [located here](https://globalfishingwatch.force.com/gfw/s/data-download).  Once extracted, I have a folder with five years worth of daily CSV files named *YYYY-MM-DD.csv*

How can I automate the import if I only want the files from 2016 and I don't want to have to individually assign each variable a new name?   [This question seems to imply it, but is more focused on extracting specific columns on import.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347823/r-selectively-importing-data-from-several-csv-files-into-single-data-frame-whil)  It would be great to combine an `rbind` statement and group 2016 into monthly data frames.

Comment: Maybe you can get all names of .csv files in your workspace (like this `list.files(pattern="*.csv")`) and then keep only those that match `2016` and import those only.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061), I think my answer there should cover all of this. Something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = "2016.*csv"), read.csv))`

Comment: If you need additional help, edit the question with details of what's not working and we can re-open.

Comment: And I'll amend my above recommendation, with hundreds of CSVs it will certainly be worth it to use `data.table::fread` for speed. Code becomes `library(data.table); result = rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern = "2016.*csv"), fread))`. If the individual data frames don't have a `date` column, add `idcol = "date"` as an argument to `rbindlist` and it will automatically create one for you based on the file names.

Comment: Edit: If you need to create the date column, do this: `library(data.table); files = list.files(pattern = "2016.*csv"); data_list = lapply(files, fread); names(data_list) = gsub(".csv", "", files, fixed = TRUE); result = rbindlist(data_list, idcol = "date")`.

Comment: That looks like it @Gregor, apologies for the duplicate, I was using imprecise language in my research.

Comment: No apologies needed! This question now serves as a helpful pointer to that other one, making it easier to find :)